# Cross Browser Compatibility Issue With SVG Animation

Tags: css, animation, svg, cross-browser, modernizr

I was wondering if anyone could help me fix my SVG animation so it works across browsers. It seems to work fine on chrome and safari but is destroyed when loaded via firefox. Failing a fix is there a way to display a message suggesting to use chrome or safari when a non-webkit browser is used? I know browser sniffing is frowned upon and I was looking at modernizr but have no idea what feature to detect for in this situation.

http://codepen.io/morkett/pen/VjByYj

```
<code>
```

The genius who made this has a message that displays when you are using firefox:

http://species-in-pieces.com/#

Any advice would greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks OK to me on Firefox, what exactly is wrong. Note that trying to avoid putting problem code directly in the question by using some dummy code will just get your question downvoted and close so I'd suggest you add a [mcve] directly into the question.

Comment: Sorry I am a stack exchange noob (the code was way too long for one post (inline SVG)and figured it could just be seen in codepen). The animation draws out fine in all browsers (dash offset and fill etc) but it doesn't seem the beat the same as it does in chrome and safari. The scaling animation (that makes it look like its beating) looks horribly out of place in firefox compared to the others. I am using firefox 48 on mac.

Comment: If the code is too long, make it smaller i.e. remove stuff till you just have the parts that show the problem. We don't really want to look for a needle in a haystack in order to help you. Note that Chrome has a bug with transform-origin in that it uses the element's dimensions rather than the viewBox dimensions to calculate the origin so it may well be that bug that's your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's super easy! You could use this code to explore if the browser is firefox :

```
<script>

    var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';

    if (isFirefox) {
        alert('Go get chrome!');
    }

</script>
```